# JS Problema con array push para carrito de compra

Tags: javascript

llevo poco tiempo en JS y no estoy pudiendo agregar objetos al carrito con .push

En la consola me dice "destino" is not defined. Refiriendose a la linea en carrito.push

No tengo idea como solucionarlo

function elegirDestino() {

```
   let eleccionDestino = packViajes.map((elDestino) => elDestino.city + " " + "$" + elDestino.precio);
    alert(eleccionDestino.join(" - "))

    eleccionDestino = prompt("A que ciudad desea viajar?")/* .toLowerCase() no funciona aca */

    let destino = packViajes.find((viaje) => viaje.city == eleccionDestino);

    if (destino != undefined) {
        return destino + seleccionarPasajes()

    } else  {
        alert("Opcion Invalida. Escriba una de las ciudades del catalogo") 
        elegirDestino()
    }
    
}

function seleccionarPasajes(unidades) {
    
    unidades = parseInt(prompt("Cuantos pasajes desea comprar?"))

    if (unidades >= 1 && unidades <= 10) {
        alert("Excelente! Que disfrute su viaje!")
        carrito.push({ 
            Ciudad: destino, 
            Precio: unidades.precio, 
            Cantidad: unidades
         }) 
         acumuladorCarrito()

    } else {
        alert("Opcion invalida. Hasta un maximo de 10 pasajes")
        seleccionarPasajes()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ese error se te devuelve porque dentro del ambito de la funcion 'seleccionarPasajes' no has declarado la propiedad o variable 'destino', el argumento que recibe tu funcion es 'unidades', y es lo unico que 'conoce' entonces tu funcion, si 'destino' es una propiedad de unidades, entonces tienes que referirla como tal 'unidades.destino', o pasar la variable destino como un argumento a la funcion